# How to add huge html in .append() function?

Tags: jquery, append

The problem with .append is that I must write all in one line like so:

```
$('#addr' + (i - 1)).append("<td>" + i + "</td><td><input id='riferimento_" + i + "' name='riferimento_" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='RIFERIMENTO' class='form-control riferimento'  /></td><td><input id='host_" + i + "' name='host_" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='HOST' class='form-control host'  /></td><td><input id='user_" + i + "' name='user_" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='USER' class='form-control user'  /></td><td><div class='opzioni' id='opzione" + i + "'>  <p id='infotime_" + i + "' class='pull-left'><p>  <a href='#' id='" + i + "' class='btn btn-danger  btn-circle  pull-right btn_delete_row'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></a> <a style='margin-right: 8px;' href='#' data-popup-open='popup_" + i + "' class='btn btn-info btn-circle pull-right more_info '><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span></a> <a hidden style='margin-right: 8px;' href='#' key='" + i + "' id='update_row_db_" + i + "' class='btn btn-primary btn-circle pull-right update_row_db '><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>  <a hidden style='margin-right: 8px;' href='#' key='" + i + "' id='add_row_db_" + i + "' class='btn btn-success btn-circle pull-right add_row_db '><span class='glyphicon  glyphicon-save'></span></a> </div></td>");
```

how can i use breaklines and format the html like this:

```
$('#addr'+(i-1)).append("
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
");
```

I'd like to have a code more readable for further changes. Maybe I'm looking at the problem in the wrong way, do you know another way?

Comment: Wrap each line in quotes and concatenate them

Comment: Generally, script tags and files are for javascript, and .html, .php files etc are for markup

Comment: If you're needing to append that much HTML dynamically you should look in to using a templating library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :-

```
var htmlToAppend;
htmlToAppend="<td>"+ i +"</td>";
htmlToAppend=htmlToAppend+"<td><input id='riferimento_"+i+"' name='riferimento_"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='RIFERIMENTO' class='form-control riferimento'/>";
htmlToAppend=htmlToAppend+"</td>";
htmlToAppend=htmlToAppend+"<td><input id='host_"+i+"' name='host_"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='HOST' class='form-control host'  /></td>";
htmlToAppend=htmlToAppend+ "<td><input id='user_"+i+"' name='user_"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='USER' class='form-control user'  /></td>
```

";

and finally

```
$('#addr'+(i-1)).append(htmlToAppend);
```

to make it more readable

Comment: I agree with your answer but one small modification I would suggest: Instead of `htmlToAppend=htmlToAppend+ more html here'`, a better way would be: `htmlToAppend += 'more html here'`

Answer (score 1):

> [Google's JavaScript style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals) recommends to use string concatenation
> instead of escaping newlines:
>
> var myString = '`<div>`
> ' + 
> '`<p> Hello World</p>`' + 
> '`<p> Use this style </p>`' + 
> '`</div>`';

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247331/3704861